# Android Webview doesn't show webpage but I can still interact with it

Tags: java, android, webview, gif

It only show a blank screen but when I tap on some part, it try to open a link so the page is responding but not showing, the webpage that I want to be loaded is [partyhard.fr](http://http//partyhard.fr)

Here is an [apk](https://www.dropbox.com/s/875bn4xtaa5bcl3/partyhard.apk?dl=0)

And here is the code ( mainactivity.java )

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String url ="http://partyhard.fr/";
    WebView view=(WebView) this.findViewById(webView);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.loadUrl(url);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Thanks for your help and don't forget that I'm new into coding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a webview layout in your main layout

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     />
```

change the on create method in your Mainactivity class with this

```
         WebView webview = new WebView(this);
         setContentView(webview);
         webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
         webview.loadUrl("http://www.example.com/");
```

allow this permission in your manifest

```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Code work but app crash at startup... I tested on GS4 Running android 5.0.1 and a Nexus 5 ( emulator ) armv7 on android 5.0.1

Comment: @user109422  try looking in your logcat why it is crashing

Comment: Ok, so I have the error : 

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.d4rkunicorn.partyhard/com.d4rkunicorn.partyhard.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.webkit.WebSettings android.webkit.WebView.getSettings()' on a null object reference

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.webkit.WebSettings android.webkit.WebView.getSettings()' on a null object reference